# save print value into a text file python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have this 2 program:

```
def calculate1():

    a4canon = (int(input('A4 paper (canon):')))*8.9
    a4rainbow = (int(input('A4 paper (rainbow):')))*7.5
    lruler = (int(input('Long ruler:')))*0.85
    sruler = (int(input('Short ruler:')))*0.55
    blue = (int(input('Blue pen:')))*0.65
    red = (int(input('Red pen:')))*0.65
    black = (int(input('Black pen:')))*0.65
    pencil = (int(input('2B Pencil:')))*2.4

    total = a4canon + a4rainbow + lruler + sruler + blue + red + black + pencil 

    a4canon1 = str(a4canon)
    a4rainbow1 = str(a4rainbow)
    lruler1 = str(lruler)
    sruler1 = str(sruler)
    blue1 = str(blue)
    red1 = str(red)
    black1 = str(black)
    pencil1 = str(pencil)

    total1 = str(total)


    return('A4 paper (canon):',a4canon1)
    return('A4 paper (rainbow):',a4rainbow1)
    return('Long ruler :',lruler1)
    return('Short ruler:',sruler1)
    return('Blue pen:',blue1)
    return('Red pen:',red1)
    return('Black pen:',black1)
    return('Pencil:',pencil1)
    return('Total:',total1)
```

and the other:

```
import calculate
def display1():
    file = open('sample.txt','w')
    file.write(calculate.calculate1())

display1()
```

The problem is that it prints:

```
TypeError: write() argument must be str, not tuple
```

Am I missing something although I have change the value into string because I want it to save into text file something like this:

```
A4 paper(canon):1 ~ 8.9
A4 paper(rainbow):1 ~ 7.5
Long ruler:1 ~ 0.85
Short ruler:1 ~ 0.55
Blue pen:1 ~ 0.65
red pen:1 ~ 0.65
Black pen:1 ~ 0.65
2B pencil:1~ 2.4
Total:22.149999999999995
```

Help and suggestion please. Thanks

it seems that when i use the:

```
file.write(str(calculate.calculate1()))
```

it only save:

```
('A4 paper (canon):', 8.9)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

File write will accept strings only that's why you are getting the error. So when you are returning you can return like this

`return("A4 paper (canon):" + str(a4canon1))` which will return a string and you can use it for file.write

or while using return value you can convert it to string

`file.write(str(calculate.calculate1()))`

Also in your definition,you have multiple return statements . Nothing will be executed after first return statement. Remove all your return statements and return a list of string instead of returning multiple strings

`return[('A4 paper (canon):',a4canon1),('A4 paper (rainbow):',a4rainbow1),('Long ruler :',lruler1),('Short ruler:',sruler1),('Blue pen:',blue1),('Red pen:',red1),('Black pen:',black1),('Pencil:',pencil1),('Total:',total1)]`

And in when capturing return value change like this

```
import calculate
def display1():
    file = open('sample.txt','w')
    lst=calculate.calculate1()
    for i in lst:
         file.write(" ".join(list(i)))

display1()
```

And also it is not advised to take inputs inside the function definition. You may need to rework on it

Answer (score 0):

**File.write** accepts string but in your case the it returns a tuple, so instead of writing tuple to file you need to convert it into string by using str() and then write it to file.

You may want to learn more about [file operations](http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/files/reading-and-writing-files-in-python) and also [type conversions.](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/type-conversion-python/)

```
  file.write(str(calculate.calculate1()))
```